# Check my answer: Prove that every open set in $\Bbb R^n$ is a countable union of open intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

I have a question. I have solved this but please can you check my solution? Thank you.

If there are any mistakes or something is missing and so on, please tell me.

This is important to me. Is this proof enough to get a successful grade on an exam?

Btw, I underlined the question with pink a pencil.

[image]

Comment: the most interesting thing is to prove that we have representation as disjoint countable union of intervals

Comment: Is what you said the related with my answer? I dont want to learn additional information. I am new learner and I am confused too much. Please check my answer? Is this right? Any does exist mistake? @Norbert

Comment: Also, what theorem of Lindelöf's are you referring to?

Comment: Both lindelöf thm and definition of open set in $\Bbb R^n$ From william wade book. @dfeuer

Comment: What is your definition of *interval* in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Does there exist mistake or incompleteness? @Dfeuer

Comment: I wish my notes looked like that, except for the pink.

Comment: I dont understand what you talk. I guess, everything what i wrote, defitions and theorems are explicit and known. But ı cannot see my mistakes or incompleteness @copper.hat

Comment: I dont understand what you talk. I guess, everything what i wrote, defitions and theorems are explicit and known. But ı cannot see my mistakes or incompleteness @GitGud

Comment: @dfeuer: What’s being used is clearly the fact that $\Bbb R^n$ is hereditarily Lindelöf, which follows from second countability. Apparently some people refer to the result that second countable spaces are Lindelöf as Lindelöf’s theorem.

Comment: I object to the sentence (and idea) that $A$ is countable implies $A = \mathbb{N}$. There is a bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ you can use.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma If for nothing else, because it can be finite.

Comment: Result: correct? Or false? @GitGud

Comment: @B11b There's a problem with saying that $A_0 \text{is countable} \implies A=\Bbb N$. Other than that people have asked you questions in order to tell you if it is correct or not, but you haven't answered.

Comment: Well, how can I correct this problem? Please can you write in appropriate way? Please. I need.. @GitGud

Comment: @B11b I can't help you, I don't know about this.

Comment: @B11b If you want to get more help, state the Lindelöf's theorem and define *interval* in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: The main thing that we need to know is your definition of *interval* in $\Bbb R^n$. Do you mean a set of the form $$[a_1,b_1)\times[a_2,b_2)\times\ldots\times[a_n,b_n)\;?$$

Comment: Hi @copper.hat I understand, there is a problem $A_0$ is countable $ \if A=\Bbb N$ please can you correct this? Please help me. I need

Comment: @GitGud: Lindelöf’s theorem isn’t a problem: see my earlier comment.

Comment: Yes, this is definition. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @B11b the problem with that is that a set if **countable** if, and only if, it is either finite or there is a bijection between the set and the natural numbers. You ignore the possibility that it might be finite.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott please you write below, my mistakes as an correct ways

Comment: I’m working on it right now.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I could show my effort. Please can you write its answer below with correct way? Please. I need to learn. Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you so so so much @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @B11b Be very happy, not everyone is lucky enough to get an answer from Brian M. Scott.

Comment: Really? But I got answer from Brian M. Scott previous time. Scott is the best to teach well and solve understandable @LordSoth

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems with your argument. The first is when you have

$$V\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in A_0}B_{\epsilon_x}(x)\;,\tag{1}$$

where $A_0$ is a countable subset of $X$, and say that $A_0=\Bbb N$. $A_0$ is **not** $\Bbb N$: it’s a subset of $X$. If it’s a countably infinite subset of $X$, then there is a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $A_0$, and you can enumerate $A_0=\{x_j:j\in\Bbb N\}$, let $B_j(x_j)=B_{\epsilon_j}(x_j)$ for each $j\in\Bbb N$, and say (as you did) that

$$V\subseteq\bigcup_{j\in\Bbb N}B_j(x_j)\;,\tag{2}$$

but you have to say that that is what you’re doing. However, $A_0$ might be finite, in which case there is no bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $A_0$.

There’s no need to do all of this, however: $(2)$ is an unnecessary rewriting of $(1)$ even when $(2)$ is correct. If $A_0$ is countable, then the union is $(1)$ is a countable union, and that’s all you need. However, I would strengthen $(1)$ and say that

$$V=\bigcup_{x\in A_0}B_{\epsilon_x}(x)\;:\tag{3}$$

you’ve actually proved this, and it’s what you need: $V$ **is** a countable union of open balls, not just a subset of a countable union of open balls.

Now we come to the larger problem. Your last step does not work at all: a ball in $\Bbb R^n$ is not an interval. To complete your proof, you need to show that an open ball in $\Bbb R^n$ is a countable union of intervals. Then you can argue like this:

> For each $x\in A_0$ there is a countable family $\mathscr{I}_x$ of intervals in $\Bbb R^n$ such that $B_{\epsilon_x}(x)=\bigcup\mathscr{I}_x$. Let $\mathscr{I}=\bigcup_{x\in A_0}\mathscr{I}_x$; then $\mathscr{I}$, being the countable union of countable sets, is countable, and $$B=\bigcup_{x\in A_0}\bigcup\mathscr{I}_x=\bigcup\mathscr{I}$$ is a countable union of intervals.

To do this, though, you have to prove that if $B_r(x)$ is any open ball in $\Bbb R^n$, then $B_r(x)$ is the union of countably many sets of the form

$$[a_1,b_1)\times[a_2,b_2)\times\ldots\times[a_n,b_n)\;.$$

I suggest the following approach.

1. First prove that $B_r(x)$ is the union of countably many sets of the form $$(a_1,b_1)\times(a_2,b_2)\times\ldots\times(a_n,b_n)\;.$$ You can do this by showing that if $y\in B_r(x)$, there are rational numbers $p_1,\dots,p_n,q_1,\dots,q_n$ such that $$y\in(p_1,q_1)\times(p_2,q_2)\times\ldots\times(p_n,q_n)\;.\tag{4}$$ There are only countably many rational numbers, so there are only countably many open boxes like $(4)$.
2. Show that each open box like $(4)$ is the union of countably many intervals. HINT: Use the fact that in $\Bbb R$, $$[a,b)=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left(a+\frac1n,b\right)\;.$$

Comment: You are amazing! Wonderful! Thank you so much! I read it and understand your solution. Thank you so much thank you:)

Comment: @B11b: You’re very welcome! I’m glad that it helped.

Comment: @Brian - That kind of feedback is priceless! ;-)

Comment: Where did the products of half-open intervals come from?

Comment: @dfeuer: That’s what is meant by *interval in* $\Bbb R^n$. I’ve seen the definition before and got an explicit confirmation that it was intended here; see the long string of comments under the question.