# It has been shown that every open set in ℝ is the union of disjoint open intervals. Is this true for $ℝ^n$ in general?

Tags: real-analysis

It has been shown that every open set in $\mathbb R$ is the union of disjoint open intervals. Is this true for $\mathbb R^n$ in general?

It seems to me that it is not, but I cannot think of an example.

Comment: How are you defining *interval* in $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: I am defining an open interval in R^n as a product on n open intervals in R.

Comment: It is not true in general for $\mathbb R^n$, but we do have the slightly weaker (but still very useful) result that [every open set can be decomposed as a countable union of almost disjoint closed intervals](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640491/every-open-subset-o-of-bbb-rd-d-geq-1-can-be-written-as-a-countable-unio)

Comment: Looks like @BrianM.Scott has been answering this question for years. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435596/check-my-answer-prove-that-every-open-set-in-bbb-rn-is-a-countable-union-of

Comment: @AlexisOlson That's a different question, since there is no requirement of disjointness there.

Comment: I think the closest $\mathbb{R}^n$-counterpart would be: "every open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written (uniquely) as a countable union of disjoint connected open sets."  It's just the case that connected open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are open intervals.

Comment: product of open intervals are rectangles.  An open disc is not a union of disjoint rectangles.

Comment: @Batominovski that captures the spirit of the question.  "intervals" was arbitrary and unimportant.  In 1-dimension connected open sets are intervals.

Answer (score 8):

It's unclear what you mean by "interval" in a higher-dimensional context. Reasonable candidates include *boxes* ( = Cartesian products of open intervals) and *open balls*. However, here's a general result showing that almost any such claim will fail even in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be some family of open sets (e.g., all open boxes), and let $U$ be a connected open set which is not an element of $\mathcal{O}$ (e.g., $U$ is an open ball). Then $U$ cannot be written as a disjoint union of elements of $\mathcal{O}$. Why? Well, suppose it could - as $U=\bigsqcup A_i$. Fix some nonempty $A_i$ in particular. Since $U\not\in\mathcal{O}$, we have $A_i\subsetneq U$; so (*why? this is where connectedness of $U$ gets used!*) we can find a point $x$ on the boundary of $A_i$, which is in $U$. Then any open set at all containing $x$ has to intersect $A_i$. But $x\in A_j$ for some $j$, since $x\in U$! So $A_i\cap A_j\not=\emptyset$, contradiction.

**EDIT: Or, as Bungo points out below, $A_i$ and $\sqcup_{j\not=i} A_j$ partition $U$ into two disjoint open sets, contradicting the assumption that $U$ was connected.**

The key difference between the two-(or higher-)dimensional case and the one-dimensional case? In one dimension, the connected open sets are easy to classify - they're exactly the open intervals! In two dimensions, though, there are *lots* of connected open sets. Really, the theorem that works for all dimensions is

> Any open set can be written as a disjoint union of connected open sets;

it's just that for $n=1$ this can be phrased in a particularly snappy way.

Comment: Maybe even simpler to note that that $A_i$ and $\cup_{n\neq i}A_n$ are disjoint nonempty open sets whose union is $U$, hence obtaining the contradiction that $U$ is disconnected?

Comment: @Bungo Yes, that's even simpler. Oh well. :P